# What will be optimized version of the given code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, checkbox

I have a block of code where i am checking checkboxes, comparing the contents of the datatable in the given code:

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
 {
    for (var i = 0; i < chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count; i++)
    {
      if (chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i].Value.Equals(dr["WorkTypeID"].ToString()))
      {
         chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i].Selected = true;
      }
    }
 }
```

Any labmda or linq expression would be great.

Comment: Optimised how? Performance? Quality of code? Something else?

Comment: Have you tried to use data binding?

Comment: Any pro dev can look on the code and say what type of optimization it is required. If you have 10 rows in datatable and 5 check boxes, then as per the above code it will iterated 50 time for actual result. So obviously , i need performance, via LINQ or LAMBDA.

Comment: > i need performance, via LINQ or LAMBDA. Actualy if you need performance, LINQ is not way to go.

Comment: "LINQ is not MAGIC" Amen. If you want to iterate less, you need a different algorithm - but depending on the requirements, there may be no way around it. And *we* can't guess what other approach may be valid. At most, we could try to improve the constant factors - but it doesn't look like there's much to be done.

Comment: OK, fine. But anyway to minimize those iterations, as far as I can see in my code, i cant do binding.

Comment: Is it possible to use some lambda exp for "inside for loop and if condition"

Comment: You should provide more information. How many items are in both collections? Is it really botleneck of your code? Doesnt seem like to me, unless something behind the scenes slows it down.

Comment: -1, for the "Any pro dev can".  What professional developers do is measure.  We're scientists - not wizards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
 {
    string cWorkTypeID = dr["WorkTypeID"].ToString();
    for (var i = 0; i < chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count; i++)
    {
         if(chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i].Value.Equals(cWorkTypeID))
           chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i].Selected =true;
    }
 }
```

if the ID on the checkboxes is diferent (that probably is),

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
 {
    string cWorkTypeID = dr["WorkTypeID"].ToString();
    for (var i = 0; i < chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count; i++)
    {
         if(chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i].Value.Equals(cWorkTypeID))
         {
            chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i].Selected = true;
            break;
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Real optimization will be a data binding.

Comment: any other way... via LINQ or LAMBDA

Comment: Sure, this code can be partially rewrited using LINQ, but this will not be an optimization

Comment: OK, fine. But anyway to minimize those iterations, as far as I can see in my code, i cant do binding.

Comment: Is it possible to use some lambda exp for "inside for loop and if condition"

Answer (score 0):

Though it does practically the same thing behind the scenes as @Aristos answer, doing it like the following will cut your lines of code down a bit:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
{
    ListItem item = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.FindByValue(dr["WorkTypeID"].ToString());
    if (item != null)
    {
         item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially performing a JOIN operation. There are [3 types of join algorithms](http://oracle-online-help.blogspot.com/2007/03/nested-loops-hash-join-and-sort-merge.html) in common use - nested loop, hash, and merge. Your code is using the nested loop algorithm - which seems appropriate for table sizes of 10 and 5, unless one or both are already sorted (in which case, a merge join may be more appropriate).

I can't imagine this being a bottleneck in any real-world application - but, we can possibly improve it a little bit with some assumptions.

1. Let's start by hoisting variables, to ensure they're not being recalculated (the JIT-optimizer will probably do this automatically, but it doesn't hurt):

   ```
    int chkBoxCount = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
    {
       string rowValue = dr["WorkTypeID"].ToString();
       for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount; i++)
       {
         var chkBox = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i];
         if (chkBox.Value.Equals(rowValue))
         {
            chkBox.Selected = true;
         }
       }
    }
   ```
2. On the assumption that rowValue is a string, let's use a cast:

   ```
    int chkBoxCount = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
    {
       string rowValue = (string)dr["WorkTypeID"];
       for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount; i++)
       {
         var chkBox = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i];
         if (chkBox.Value.Equals(rowValue))
         {
            chkBox.Selected = true;
         }
       }
    }
   ```
3. Since we're never unselecting a checkbox, and a bool compare should be faster on average than a string compare:

   ```
    int chkBoxCount = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
    {
       string rowValue = (string)dr["WorkTypeID"];
       for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount; i++)
       {
         var chkBox = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i];
         if (!chkBox.Selected && chkBox.Value.Equals(rowValue)) 
         {
            chkBox.Selected = true;
         }
       }
    }
   ```
4. Assuming each checkbox value is unique, we can stop iterating when we've found a result:

   ```
    int chkBoxCount = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
    {
       string rowValue = (string)dr["WorkTypeID"];
       for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount; i++)
       {
         var chkBox = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i];
         if (!chkBox.Selected && chkBox.Value.Equals(rowValue)) 
         {
            chkBox.Selected = true;
            break; // stop looking
         }
       }
    }
   ```
5. Since you have 10 rows, and 5 checkboxes - we should reverse the loops. Since we break on the inner loop when value is found, making the inner loop the larger of the 2 is more efficient:

   ```
    int chkBoxCount = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount; i++)
    {
      var chkBox = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i];
      if (chkBox.Selected) continue;
      foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
      {
         string rowValue = (string)dr["WorkTypeID"];
         if (chkBox.Value.Equals(rowValue)) 
         {
            chkBox.Selected = true;
            break;
         }
      }
    }
   ```
6. Assuming you don't care about culture or case sensitive comparisons, we can use OrdinalIgnoreCase:

   ```
    int chkBoxCount = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount; i++)
    {
      var chkBox = chkboxListWorkTypes.Items[i];
      if (chkBox.Selected) continue;
      foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
      {
         string rowValue = (string)dr["WorkTypeID"];
         if (string.Equals(chkBox.Value, rowValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
         {
            chkBox.Selected = true;
            break;
         }
      }
    }
   ```

That's about the best I can do. I'd be surprised if there was any measurable difference on such a small dataset. So, here's what you should *really* do:

```
 var workTypeIds = dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(dr => (string)dr["WorkTypeId"]);
 foreach (var chk in chkBoxListWorkTypes) 
 {
     if (workTypeIds.Contains(chk.Value))
     {
        chk.Selected = true;
     }
 }
```

Or, with an Each extension:

```
 var workTypeIds = dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(dr => (string)dr["WorkTypeId"]);
 chkBoxListWorkTypes.Where(c => workTypeIds.Contains(c.Value)).Each(c => c.Selected = true);
```

which may be slightly slower, but reads a lot better IMO.